# Apple *.caf files in HTML5 <audio> tag

Tags: html, caf

Can I include *.caf files in HTML5  tags or do I need to convert them first?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example:

```
    <audio controls>
            <source src="radio.opus" type="audio/ogg; codecs=opus">
            <source src="radio.caf" type="audio/x-caf; codecs=opus">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
    </audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert them to OGG and MP3 at least.